# Testing HTTP Callouts Using zipped files in Static Resources

Tags: httpcalloutmock

As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm), we can use `Mock.setStaticResource` method to fake single webservice response in test class.

```
StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
mock.setStaticResource('myStaticResourceName');
mock.setStatusCode(200);
mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

> Are there any method available in apex to use a read zip files for different scenarios?

Otherwise creating different static resource for each response is possible but not the best solution.

Comment: No, one static resource is one response. Plus, we still don't have a good way to read binary data or parse zip files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question; as mentioned by Brian this is not possible at the moment.